# TransportError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request While Using SUDS (Python)

Tags: http, python-2.7, suds, http-status-code-400

I'm getting this error while trying to access a WS using SUDS in Python.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong? (Yes, I'm quite new to Python)

**Python Code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from suds.client import Client
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
import datetime
import logging
from email.header    import Header
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib         import SMTP_SSL
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter

# Configurações do Log
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', filename='ConfirmarPedidoSmsBroker-Test.log',level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
now = datetime.datetime.now()

#Informações para o consumo do WS
WSDL_URL = "http://123.168.1.132:8084/abc-ws-provider/AbcBrokerBSv1.0?wsdl"

#Criações dos tipos para gerar o objeto complexo
class Evale(object):
    codigoDeAutorizacao = 1234567

class Cliente (object):
    identificacaoDoCliente = 12345
    codigoDoCliente = 101010
    razaoSocial = "None"

class Telefone (object):
    ddd = 21
    numero = 1234-5678

class Contato (object):
    telefone = Telefone()

class HorariosDeAtendimento (object):
    diaDaSemana = "Sunday"
    horaInicial = "07:30:00"
    horaFinal = "20:00:00"

class TipoDeAtendimentoRealizado (object):
    horariosDeAtendimento = HorariosDeAtendimento()

class Revenda (object):
    cliente = Cliente()
    identificacaoDoEndereco = 987654
    codigoDoEndereco = 8765567
    numeroDoDocumento = "2312341"
    filialDoDocumento = 0009
    digitoDoDocumento = 32

class RevendaPrincipal(object):
    revenda = Revenda()

class RevendaAlternativa(object):
    revenda = Revenda()

class EnderecoDoSolicitante(object):
    logradouro = "Street Test"
    numeroDoEndereco = 80
    complemento = "Penth"
    municipio = "New York"
    bairro = "Brooklin"
    cep = "74123"
    estado = "NY"

class PedidoSms(object):
    identificacaoDaTransacao = 1010
    evale = Evale()
    revendaPrincipal = RevendaPrincipal()
    revendaAlternativa = RevendaAlternativa()
    enderecoDoSolicitante = EnderecoDoSolicitante()
    latitudeDoEnderecoDoSolicitante = -92.123443
    longitudeDoEnderecoDoSolicitante = -81.98765

class ConfirmarPedidoSmsBrokerRequest(object):
    pedidoSms = PedidoSms()

class ConfirmarPedidoSmsBroker_InputVariable (object):
    confirmarPedidoSmsBrokerRequest = ConfirmarPedidoSmsBrokerRequest()

class Input (object):
    confirmarPedidoSmsBroker_InputVariable = ConfirmarPedidoSmsBroker_InputVariable()


# Método que chama o serviço
def sendRequestToService():
    confPedido = Input()
    logging.info("ConfirmarPedidoSmsBroker-Test at " + str(now))
    logging.info("WSDL_URL " + WSDL_URL)
    logging.info("Passing URL to Client")
    client = Client(WSDL_URL)
    logging.info("Trying to access the service")
    response = client.service.confirmarPedidoSmsBroker(confPedido)
    logginf.info(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sendRequestToService()
```

**And this is the error that I get whenever I try to run it.**

```
06/02/2014 17:06:17 - ConfirmarPedidoSmsBroker-Test at 2014-02-06 17:06:17.443663
06/02/2014 17:06:17 - WSDL_URL http://111.168.1.132:8084/abc-ws-provider/AbcBrokerBSv1.0?wsdl
06/02/2014 17:06:17 - Passing URL to Client
06/02/2014 17:06:17 - Import:0x10ab61d10, imported schema (http://www.abcdef.com.br/Abab/BO/v3) at (http://123.168.1.132:8084/../../../../../Abc/Def/Somethingv3.xsd), failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 560, in download
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/reader.py", line 79, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/reader.py", line 95, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/transport/https.py", line 60, in open
    return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/suds/transport/http.py", line 64, in open
    raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
TransportError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your WSDL service is responding with a 400 error for the request you passed (perhaps it's missing required arguments, etc..) please try to [add debug logging](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#LOGGING) like so:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

After doing that, give it another go (you can just open the interactive python shell and paste in your code, enable logging and invoke the `sendRequestToService` function.

Please revise your question with updates and I will revise my answer as appropriate.